# Spark Yarn /tmp No such file or directory

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, mapr

I am getting error in my spark jobs and they error are usually similar to one shown below. A node in cluster has around 256 GB of memory and around 8 cores, also I have specified executor memory as 4GB and extra 4GB overhead. For shuffle I have specified memory fraction as 0.5, by all this I want to indicate it does not seems like memory issue. However I am not able to figure out what could be issue and this comes up in one stage or another, I reran my job multiple times and this comes at multiple points. You can assume we have infrastructure of around 200+ nodes with decent configuration.

Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 12 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.11 in stage 2.0 (TID 27, lgpbd1107.sgp.ladr.com): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/hadoop-mapr/nm-local-dir/usercache/names/appcache/application_1485048538020_113554/3577094671485456431296_lock (No such file or directory)

I am unable to figure out whether its issue related to application or infrastructure. Could someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

[It is due to the tmpwatch utility,](https://community.mapr.com/thread/9467) which runs daily on CentOS systems to clean up `/tmp/files` not recently accessed.   The `NodeManager` service will not recreate the top level `hadoop.tmp.dir` (which defaults to `/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}`) when it launches a job.

Now you have two options:

***Option -1:*** Go to `/etc/cron.daily/tmp-watch` and exclude this directory from cleaning up daily. `/tmp/hadoop-mapr/nm-local-dir/filecache`

***Option -2:*** Go to

> core-site.xml and add/change value of `hadoop.tmp.dir` property --- default is `/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}`

or

> yarn-site.xml and add/change value of `yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs` property --- default is `${hadoop.tmp.dir}/nm-local-dir`

Comment: Can you elaborate more,  I read ran my job around 10 times  at different intervals and got similar error.  Job starts and fails within 20 minutes, I am assuming  20 minutes  is not large enough  within which  tmp watch will delete files.